# Vimeo videos won't play in og:video posts

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, vimeo

I'm having a problem with Vimeo video not playing in open graph 'liked posts'.

If I set the `og:video` tag to a Youtube video the video will play correctly on a 'liked post'. However `og:video` pointing to a Vimeo url will not render the video once you push play it just displays a white space.

If I examine the FB post in chrome inspector. It looks like there are proper tags there to include a swf video. The post renders an Iframe like:

```
<div>
    <div data-ft="{&quot;tn&quot;:&quot;H&quot;}">
        <div class="mtm exploded">
            <div id="u_0_2v" style="width:398px;height:224px" class="swfObject">
                <iframe width="398" height="224" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" src="https://attachment.fbsbx.com/external_iframe.php#channel=u_0_2v&amp;origin=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com"></iframe>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Inside the iframe looks like. You can see the `<object>` tag for the video.

```
<html class="">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script>function envFlush(a){function b(c){for(var d in a)c[d]=a[d];}if(window.requireLazy){window.requireLazy(['Env'],b);}else{Env=window.Env||{};b(Env);}}</script>
    <title>Facebook</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net/rsrc.php/v2/yB/r/VwdVfke9-ss.css">

    <script src="https://fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net/rsrc.php/v2/yP/r/QkHHSZhu7AB.js" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
    <script>(require("ServerJSDefine")).handleDefines([["BootloaderConfig",[],{},329]]);new (require("ServerJS"))().handle({"require":[["lowerDomain"],["OnloadHooks"]]});</script>
    <script src="https://fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net/rsrc.php/v2/yl/r/D5DIP3i0cDn.js" async="" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
    <script src="https://fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net/rsrc.php/v2/yT/r/SFHAfJIaKB4.js" async="" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
    <script src="https://fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net/rsrc.php/v2/yS/r/GpX_IoVUwvc.js" async="" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
    <script src="https://fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net/rsrc.php/v2/yn/r/7-bi9IUZgGw.js" async="" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
    <script src="https://fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net/rsrc.php/v2/y7/r/bg0Ivm0NNg2.js" async="" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
    <script src="https://fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net/rsrc.php/v2/y1/r/G3mPckdpbn8.js" async="" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
    <script src="https://fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net/rsrc.php/v2/ye/r/9o41rn2Yd5O.js" async="" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
</head>
<body class="webkit chrome mac Locale_en_US" dir="ltr">
    <div id="swf_placeholder">
        <span>
            <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="https://player.vimeo.com/video/5972531" height="224" width="398" id="f1ea12fd2c">
                <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="never">
                <param name="flashvars" value="height=224&amp;width=398">
                <param name="movie" value="https://player.vimeo.com/video/5972531">
                <param name="swf" value="https://player.vimeo.com/video/5972531">
                <param name="id" value="swf_u_0_2v">
                <param name="holder" value="u_0_2v">
                <param name="color" value="#FFFFFF">
                <param name="width" value="398">
                <param name="height" value="224">
                <param name="version" value="0">
                <param name="scale" value="scale">
                <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true">
                <param name="salign" value="tl">
                <param name="wmode" value="opaque">
            </object>
        </span>
    </div>


    <script type="text/javascript">requireLazy(["Bootloader"], function(Bootloader) {Bootloader.setResourceMap({"mm0IE":{"type":"js","crossOrigin":1,"src":"https:\/\/fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net\/rsrc.php\/v2\/yl\/r\/D5DIP3i0cDn.js"},"YzwHG":{"type":"js","crossOrigin":1,"src":"https:\/\/fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net\/rsrc.php\/v2\/yT\/r\/SFHAfJIaKB4.js"},"9IG40":{"type":"js","crossOrigin":1,"src":"https:\/\/fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net\/rsrc.php\/v2\/yS\/r\/GpX_IoVUwvc.js"},"nzcun":{"type":"js","crossOrigin":1,"src":"https:\/\/fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net\/rsrc.php\/v2\/yn\/r\/7-bi9IUZgGw.js"},"dj+Kz":{"type":"js","crossOrigin":1,"src":"https:\/\/fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net\/rsrc.php\/v2\/y7\/r\/bg0Ivm0NNg2.js"},"k6\/kg":{"type":"js","crossOrigin":1,"src":"https:\/\/fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net\/rsrc.php\/v2\/y1\/r\/G3mPckdpbn8.js"},"n09pR":{"type":"js","crossOrigin":1,"src":"https:\/\/fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net\/rsrc.php\/v2\/ye\/r\/9o41rn2Yd5O.js"},"wLiBG":{"type":"css","permanent":1,"crossOrigin":1,"src":"https:\/\/fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net\/rsrc.php\/v2\/yB\/r\/VwdVfke9-ss.css"}});if (false) {Bootloader.enableBootload({});}});</script>
    <script type="text/javascript">requireLazy(["InitialJSLoader"], function(InitialJSLoader) {InitialJSLoader.loadOnDOMContentReady(["mm0IE","YzwHG","9IG40","nzcun","dj+Kz","k6\/kg","n09pR"]);});</script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        requireLazy(["Bootloader"], function(Bootloader) {Bootloader.configurePage(["wLiBG"]);});

        (require("ServerJSDefine")).handleDefines([]);require("InitialJSLoader").handleServerJS({"require":[["ExternalIFrameFlash","init",[],[]]]});

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```